# Referencing the Facebook SDK in my Android project

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-android-sdk, android-library

I'm trying to reference the Facebook SDK to my existing Android project. I've been going through the given tutorial in the Facebook site. So here's what I've done:

1. I copied the Facebook SDK folder to my workspace.
2. Went to Project->Properties->Android
3. Set the "Is Library" radio button to true and pressed on the "ADD" button.

But I don't see in the popping dialog anything, it's just blank, no SDK.

What am I missing here?

Here's the workspace folder, and the Facebook SDK folder is located in it:

[image: link]

And here's the Android Properties. As you can see there's no Facebook SDK there. It's just blank:

[image: link]

Comment: You don't need to set "Is Library" to true.

Comment: Did you follow this tutorial? http://developers.facebook.com/docs/mobile/android/build/

Comment: @slybloty Yes, I've seen that tutorial, I don't see the facebook SDK in there. I suppose to put that folder in the workspace right?

Comment: Grab the whole Facebook SDK, preferably using git, and put where you want. Make sure you have permissions on that folder. And then add the reference to the SDK into your project. http://developers.facebook.com/docs/mobile/android/build/#sdk

Comment: @slybloty Mind looking at my comments of the answer please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> So here's what you've done:
>
> 1. Copied the Facebook SDK folder to my workspace.
> 2. Went to Project -> Properties -> Android
> 3. Set the "Is Library" radio button to true and pressed on the "ADD" button.

Well, you are not supposed to do the Steps 2 and 3. The Facebook SDK is already coded to be a library project and you just need a reference to it in your existing application. Hence, the ADD button should be pressed in the existing project and it should reference the Facebook SDK.

Here is what you need to do :

1. Go the [website](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk) and get the contents by using git or just zip everything using the ZIP button
2. Put the Facebook SDK folder in your workspace (no need to select it "Is Library" )
3. Select your **Existing Android Project**
4. **Right Click -> Properties -> Android**
5. In the Library section, click on **Add** (by doing this step you are adding a reference to the Facebook SDK in your existing application)
6. Select **Facebook SDK** there

   You are good to go!